Proving statistically $\epsilon$-indistinguishable scheme is also $\epsilon$-adversarial indistinguishable
We say that $(\operatorname{Gen}, \operatorname{Enc}, \operatorname{Dec})$ with message and ciphertext spaces $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ is a statistically $\epsilon$-indistinguishable secure SKE (symmetric key encryption) if for every $m_0,m_1 \in \mathcal{M}$ and every $T \subseteq \mathcal{C}$,
$$| \operatorname{Pr}[\operatorname{Enc}_K(m_0) \in T] − \operatorname{Pr}[\operatorname{Enc}_K(m_1) \in T]| \leq \epsilon,$$
where the probabilities are taken over $K \leftarrow \operatorname{Gen}()$ and the randomness of $\operatorname{Enc}$.
In analogy with adversarial indistinguishability, we say that an encryption scheme
$(\operatorname{Gen}, \operatorname{Enc}, \operatorname{Dec})$ satisfies $\epsilon$-adversarial indistinguishability if every adversary $\mathcal{A}$ succeeds at the adversarial indistinguishability experiment explained below, with probability at most $\frac{1+\epsilon}{2}$:

$\mathcal{A}$ outputs a pair of messages $(m_0,m_1) \in \mathcal{M}$.
A random key $K \leftarrow \operatorname{Gen}()$ and a bit $b \leftarrow \{0, 1\}$ are sampled. The ciphertext $c \leftarrow \operatorname{Enc}_K(m_b)$ is computed and given to $\mathcal{A}$.
$\mathcal{A}$ outputs a bit $b′$ and succeeds if $b = b′$.

I want to show that if the encryption scheme $(\operatorname{Gen}, \operatorname{Enc}, \operatorname{Dec})$ is statistically $\epsilon$-indistinguishable,
then it also satisfies $\epsilon$-adversarial indistinguishability.
I can prove the statement if I assume the adversary $\mathcal{A}$ is deterministics. I mean, I assume that $\mathcal{A}$ divides cipherspace $\mathcal{C}$ to two parts $\mathcal{C}_0$ and $\mathcal{C}_1$ such that $\mathcal{C}_0\cap\mathcal{C}_1=\emptyset$ and $\mathcal{C}_0\cup\mathcal{C}_1=\mathcal{C}$. Then when a ciphertext $c$ is given to $\mathcal{A}$, it guesses $0$ if $c \in \mathcal{C}_0$, and guesses $1$ if $c \in \mathcal{C}_1$.
To prove this I put $T=\mathcal{C}_0$ in statistically $\epsilon$-indistinguishability definition, and use some basic properties of probability like probability of complement of an event.
But I think I cannot assume that adversary $\mathcal{A}$ is deterministic, and I should prove the statement for every adversary, including probabilistic ones. For example an adversary may guess $0$ with probability $0.3$ and guess $1$ with probability $0.7$, given a ciphertext $c'$, but guess $0$ with probability $0.9$ and guess $1$ with probability $0.1$, given another ciphertext $c''$.
In this case I cannot partition the cipherspace. How should I prove the statement in the case including probabilistic adversaries?

I thought of reducing the "every adversary" to "deterministic adversaries" and show if we prove it for deterministic adversaries, it's also correct for every adversary. But I don't know how to do a reduction, or I don't know even if this is correct.


I haven't checked the logic of the reduction. But why do you think you can't use a deterministic adversary? You are proving a contrapositive. "Not adversarial" implies not "statistical". To show "not adversarial", you only need one counter example. Probabilistic or not.
